# Pass same instance of complexe object between two fragment

Tags: android, fragment, bundle, instance

I have to fragment A and B and a object list of the class MyClass. 
My goal is to pass the instances of the objects in the list from A to B.

For the moment i use the GSON library like as follow

```java
class A extends Fragment{
   private List<MyClass> list;

   ...

   public void startB(){
       Bundle params = new Bundle();
       params.putString("myClassList", new Gson().toJson(this.list));
       loader.loadFragment("B_CLASS_TAG", params);
   }

}


class B extends Fragment{
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Type listType = new TypeToken<List<MyClass>>(){}.getType();
        recipients = new Gson().fromJson(params.getString("myClassList"), listType);
    }

}
```

With this i can get back the object list in the B fragment thei all have the same values but they are not the same instances that i have in the A class. Is there somehow an way to get the same instances ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use "putSerializable" instead of "putString"

Send Data From Fragment A

```
 Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
 bundle.putSerializable("list", (Serializable) list)
 fragmentb.setArguments(bundle);
```

Receive Data In Fragment B

```
  public List<Integer> listData = (List<Integer>) getArguments().getSerializable("list");
```

Here, we are converting list in serializable and while retrieving data typecast it to List.

If there is any doubt, please comment.

Comment: It seem to work fine, but can you explain me what is the difference between a string describing and object and a serializable ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for `GSON` or converting into `String`. `List` implementations are already `serializable`, you can put them in Bundle and send one from One `Fragment` to Another.

For sending the data from `Fragment` A

```
  public void startB(){
       Bundle params = new Bundle();
       params.putSerializable("myClassList", (Serializable) this.list);
       loader.loadFragment("B_CLASS_TAG", params);
   }
```

in `Fragment` B, to receive the data

```
 recipients =  (List<MyClass>)getArguments().getSerializable("myClassList")
```

Comment: I can't use this, because i get an error which said that LIst dont implement serializable

Comment: just cast them. List implementations are already serializable.